# Use computed twig to get last item in a multi value composite field

Tags: webforms

I want to use a computed twig element in a webform to give me the value of the last item in a multi value composite field. the name of the field is destinations, and it has a departure_date field and a country field .

if I use `{{ data.destination_and_date[data.destination_and_data|length].departure_date }}`

it only gives me the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to use Twig's [last](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/last.html) filter.

Below is an example of getting the last value from a multiple select element. This example can also be applied to multiple value composite element.

```
select:
  '#type': select
  '#title': select
  '#multiple': true
  '#options': days
computed_twig:
  '#type': computed_twig
  '#title': computed_twig
  '#template': "Values<br/>\r\n<ul>\r\n{% for value in data.select %}\r\n   <li>{{ value }}</li>\r\n{% endfor %}\r\n</ul>\r\n\r\nLast<br/>\r\n{{ data.select|last }}<br/>"
  '#ajax': true
```